# How to disable function onclick programmatically button

Tags: javascript, android, for-loop, button

this is my programmatically button, there is the error null pointer exception in logcat.

This is my way to loop the button.But the disable button for the button cannot function.When i click on "save" button the programmatically button will disable.  is it my way to disable button is incorrect?

```
 String CountQuery = "SELECT * FROM Category";
    db = new DBController(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db2 = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor1 = db2.rawQuery(CountQuery, null);
    {
        int num = cursor1.getCount();
        Button[] valueB = new Button[num];
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {

            String SelectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Category where CategoryID='" + i + "'";
            db = new DBController(getActivity());
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(SelectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String categoryName = cursor.getString(1);
                String coordinateX = cursor.getString(2);
                String coordinateY = cursor.getString(3);

                valueB[i] = new Button(getActivity());
                valueB[i].setText("" + categoryName);
                valueB[i].setId(i);
                valueB[i].setOnTouchListener(this);

                params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 100);
                params.leftMargin = Integer.parseInt(coordinateX);
                params.topMargin = Integer.parseInt(coordinateY);

                final int finalI = i;
                valueB[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "asdasd" + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(finalI);
                    }
                });
                mRrootLayout.addView(valueB[i],params);
            }

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (i[0] = 1; i[0] < num; i[0]++) {
                        valueB[i[0]].setOnTouchListener(null);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not using `valueB[i].setEnabled(false)` also edit your post with more details because it not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the onclick listener by using `valueB[i].setOnClickListener(null);`

Comment: yes, it work but how if i click on another button, to disable this this array button?

Comment: You can differentiate your buttons by setting unique TAG by setTag() method.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the button by using `setClickable` method.

```
valueB[i].setClickable(false);
```

or you can user `setEnabled` method also like

```
valueB[i].setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: is it possible to make it when i click on another button and disable this array button?